If someone killed accidentally and has no family members and he is not a ger can his friend kill him?
If the person who was accidentally killed doesn't have any living family members to avenge him, can he be avenged by a friend? Does the killer need to seek refuge in an ir miklat?

A person does not have even distant relatives only if he is a convert.

Welcome to the site. The third question should be asked as a separate one.

Everyone who isn't a ger (or wholly descended from now deceased single-child gerim) is related to me, at least, and I'm alive (currently).

Welcome to MiYodeya Naama and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

The Ohr Same’ach (Hilchos Rotze’ach 6:12) writes that even in a case where there is no need to protect the murderer from the Goel Hadam, nevertheless he is still required to be exiled as an atonement.
He brings two proofs:
A. The Gemara says that even if the murderer already died, we still bring his body to the Ir Miklat (Makkos 11b).
B. If one accidentally killed an Eved Kena’ani, who halachicly has no relatives, nevertheless he is still required to be exiled (Makkos 8b).
